# How can I uncollapse a footer menu?

Tags: navigation, bootstrap-theme

I'm theming with Boostrap right now in Drupal 8 and created a footer menu with a bunch of links. The menu is displaying collapsed right now, but I want it to be uncollapsed and display like a default navbar.

[image]

While bootstrap displays as collapsed

[image]

Comment: You have the wrong word, collapsed is when you can't see it. The correct word for how the boostrap looks is "inline". So you want them un-align them. This is a CSS issue, not a Drupal issue. You'll have to highlight one of the links and inspect element with your browser. Look for `display: inline-block` or `float: left;` so all you gotta do is override the div class on your theme's CSS with `display: block! important;` or `float: none !important`;

Comment: Thanks. I added the display: inline-block !important; that you recommended and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Edit all of your footer's child menu links and check-mark on each of them *show as expanded*.

[image]

Comment: I already did. Maybe I wasn't clear enough on what I need help for. The _show as expanded box_ does nothing since none of the menu items have children. It's definitely a Bootstrap issue because the menu displays correctly when I switch over to Bartik. Here are some screenshots https://imgur.com/a/P72wS0Y